# How do I debounce an event handler in react with lodash?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

// constructor
this.inputChangeHandler2 = debounce(this.inputChangeHandler, 100);

// html
<textarea onChange={this.inputChangeHandler2} />
```

Nothing is happening here when I try to use lodash debounce function. I put a breakpoint inside inputChangeHandler and if never hits.

Comment: Have you tried -> `debounce(this.inputChangeHandler.bind(this), 100)`?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Without any context / producible example, we can't help you much.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what problems your having.

But below I've knocked up a snippet working with lodash debounce.   Maybe compare this to yours and see what's different.

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {lasttime: "?"}
  }
  changed () {
    this.setState({lasttime: new Date().getTime()});
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <textarea onChange={_.debounce(this.changed.bind(this), 100)}/>
        <div>{this.state.lasttime}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<React.Fragment>
  <Test/>
</React.Fragment>, document.querySelector('#mount'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: This fires but `event` is no longer passed.

Answer (score 2):

Because React uses [synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) you can't extract the value inside a debounced function (the event doesn't exist anymore). You'll need a standard event handler (`onChange` in the code) to get the value, and a debounce function (`setValue`) to to set it:

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = { text: '' };
  
  setValue = _.debounce(text => this.setState({ text }), 300);
  
  onChange = e => this.setValue(e.target.value);
  
  render () {
    const { text } = this.state;
  
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.onChange} defaultValue={text} />
        <div>{text}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try e.persist() (if you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way)

```
class Abc extends React.Component {

 inputChangeHandler2 = (e)=> {
  //e(event will be available here)
  //your code
 }

hChange = e => {
 e.persist();
 _.debounce(() => this.inputChangeHandler2(e), 300);
}

render () {
 return (
  <div>
    <input onChange={this.hChange.bind(this)} />
  </div>
  );
 }
}
```